# On which partition should I install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I'm preparing to install Ubuntu Linux in replacement of Windows 7 (which is what my computer was preloaded with).

[image: Partition table]

Which of these partitions do I use?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu 16.04.1 you should delete all partitions and then let the installer auto-partition the blank hard drive. Only do this if you don't have any data you need on the drive because everything will be deleted.

**EDIT:** I later learned from your comments that you had setup a [dual boot](https://raffyememon.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/how-to-install-dual-boot-linux-from-windows-using-unetbootin/) with [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) and were booting from the hard drive itself, so the answer is NOT to delete all partitions.

There are two ways:

1. if you want to keep the existing Windows installation, you should resize the largest partition in order to leave some free space where Ubuntu can be installed. Exit the installer, boot Windows, resize partition with Disk Management (run `diskmgmt.msc`), reboot into UNetbootin, start the installer and select the free space. One thing you should be careful about if you go this route is that MBR disks cannot have more than four primary partitions, so you could possibly have to convert the disk to GPT.
2. if you don't care about Windows, you can delete its partitions (the NTFS ones) to reclaim free space and then install and let GRUB configure for a single operating system.

Unfortunately, this comes late since you already followed my instructions; it is partly my fault for not asking you what the 4GB FAT32 parttion was and assuming you had booted from a removable media not shown in the screenshot. I've learned from this to ask more questions instead of rushing to answer, and it can be a lesson for you, too, to better describe your situation adding details that are not self-evident.

Comment: I believe you press the `-` key to delete a partition. I.e., you should destroy the partitions, not format them.

Comment: I've tried every partition, selecting it and pressing the '-' (minus)  key doesn't do anything.

Comment: Actually, the Ubuntu installer should have given you a message saying something like "existing os detected" and offered you to "delete existing os and install Ubuntu". Coud you go back nd check?

Comment: I wasn't supposed to delete the partitions. You had me delete the entire computer! There is now no operating system!

Comment: I can't reload Ubuntu onto there, because I had used put it on the computer with the 'Unetbootin' tool!

Comment: Sorry to have made you do the wrong thing, I had added to the answer that doing so would delete all data on the hard drive. I thought you had created a usb drive with the Ubuntu ISO and booted from there. Actually, I was wondering what you had a fat32 partition for. I was misguided by common practice and lack of details about your specific situation.

Comment: .. Can I fix it by getting an Ubuntu installation disk?

Comment: Of course, I would use unetbootin or yumi on another pc to create a bootable usb with the Ubuntu iso and install from there. Please, reassure me that you didn't delete any valuable data you were keeping on the hard drive: if it's only the os then it's no irreversible damage.

Comment: I deleted every partition. Everything is gone. Ubuntu and Windows are inaccessible. But I didn't need anything on it.

Comment: And I'm talking about an actual CD, not a USB. I can order an Ubuntu CD from eBay.

Comment: Yes, a cd is just as good.